# Command line to burn DVD+R DL media on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, dvd

A Plextor PX-750A on a Linux system has made many DVD+R DL coasters while trying to burn an 8GB DVD .iso file with growisofs and the Schilling cdrecord program.

I tried growisofs first:

```
growisofs --version
* growisofs by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.0,
  front-ending to genisoimage: genisoimage 1.1.8 (Linux)
```

The command line was:

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr1=SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
```

Removal of the `-dvd-compat` option was also attempted.

Schilling cdrtools was also tried:

```
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.00 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 1995-2010 Jörg Schilling
```

The command line was:

```
/usr/local/bin/cdrecord -v dev=ATAPI:1,0,0 SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
```

In both cases, the burn aborts half way through as though it writes a layer and croaks when it should move to the second layer.

growisofs:

```
 4275175424/8434493440 (50.7%) @1.6x, remaining 22:03 RBU 100.0% UBU  94.4%
:-[ WRITE@LBA=1fdb40h failed with SK=3h/ASC=0Ch/ACQ=00h]: Input/output error
:-( write failed: Input/output error
```

cdrecord:

```
Track 01: 4205 of 8043 MB written (fifo  99%) [buf  97%]   2.4x./usr/local/bin/cdrecord: Input/output error. write_g1: scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  2A 00 00 20 DA 10 00 00 10 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 95 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x0C Qual 0x00 (write error) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid)
cmd finished after 0.019s timeout 200s

write track data: error after 4409294848 bytes
/usr/local/bin/cdrecord: A write error occured.
/usr/local/bin/cdrecord: Please properly read the error message above.
```

Looking at the media after the burn, it appears to have written data from the inside to the outside - giving the impression that it wrote one layer fully and then errored out when that layer ended.  In several attempts, each failure is at about 50% of the way through the burn of:

```
$ ls -lh SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 7.9G 2014-05-14 07:53 SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
```

Begin 2014/05/23 edit:

The cdrecord man page says:

```
Cdrecord functional options
  ...
  driveropts=option list
    ...
    layerbreak
      Switch  a  drive  with  DVD-R/DL  medium  into layer jump
      recording recording mode and  use  automatic  layer-break
      position setup.

      By  default,  DVD-R/DL  media  is  written  in sequential
      recording mode that completely fills up both layers.

    layerbreak=value
      Set up  a  manual  layer-break  value  for  DVD-R/DL  and
      DVD+R/DL.   The  specified  layer-break value must not be
      set to less than half of the recorded data size and  must
      not be set to more than the remaining Layer 0 size of the
      medium.  The manual layer-break value needs to be a  mul-
      tiple  of  the  ECC  sector size which is 16 logical 2048
      byte sectors in case of DVD media  and  32  logical  2048
      byte sectors in case of HD-DVD or BD media.

      Cdrecord  does  not  allow to write DL media in case that
      the total amount of data is less then the Layer 0 size of
      the  medium  except  when  a  manual layer-break has been
      specified by using the layerbreak=value option.
```

Use of layerbreak without a manually computed breakpoint gives:

```
cdrecord -v driveropts=layerbreak dev=ATAPI:1,0,0 SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
...
cdrecord: Bad layer break value ''.
...
```

After some research, I found a patch to an older cdrecord that contained an "optimal layer break computation".  With a little experimentation, I found that I could compute the "optimal layer break" in a shell:

```
echo -e "a = $(isosize SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso)\nb = a / 2048 / 2\nb - 1 + 16 - ( b - 1 ) % 16\n" | bc
```

This gave a layerbreak value of 2059216.  In fact, for grins, I tried adjusting the value up and down.  For some layerbreak values (like 2059215) cdrecord would report:

```
cdrecord: Layer break at 2059215 is not properly aligned.
```

Hopeful, I tried:

```
cdrecord -v driveropts=layerbreak=2059216 dev=ATAPI:1,0,0 SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
```

And still got a coaster and write error:

```
Track 01: 4205 of 8043 MB written (fifo  99%) [buf  97%]   2.4x./usr/local/bin/cdrecord: Input/output error. write_g1: scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  2A 00 00 20 DB 60 00 00 10 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 95 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x0C Qual 0x00 (write error) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid)
cmd finished after 0.022s timeout 200s

write track data: error after 4409982976 bytes
/usr/local/bin/cdrecord: A write error occured.
/usr/local/bin/cdrecord: Please properly read the error message above.
```

End of 2014/05/23 edit.

This issue occured on a server where there were no GUI tools installed.  I am looking for a way to burn dual layer DVDs from the command-line.

Comment: Odd. `growisofs` works fine for me burning dual-layer blanks. Must be drive-specific.

Comment: Interesting that your response posted at the same time I was attempting use of a USB-attached LG GE24LU20.  The LG drive works fine and burns at 4x instead of 2.5x.  I now also just found that the Plextor PX-750A firmware is at 1.01 whereas the manufacturer issued a 1.03 firmware in 2006 that mentions "Improved writing performance on DVD+/-RW media
Raised writing speed on DVD-R DL media to 8x".

Comment: If a firmware update fixes it, please answer your own question giving details.

Comment: A firmware update did correct the failure; an answer has been posted and selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try another DVD writer.

   > Failing commands functioned properly when used with a USB-attached LG
   >   M/N GE24LU20 DVD writer.
2. Check DVD writer firmware revision.  Upgrade the firmware if a newer revision is available.

   > Both `growisofs` and `cdrecord` commands above that fail on a Plextor
   >   PX-750A-UF 1.01 burner succeed with the same drive after a firmware
   >   update to [PX-750A-UF 1.03](http://plextoramericas.com/index.php/download?task=viewcategory&catid=85).
   >
   > ```
   > /usr/local/bin/cdrecord -v dev=ATAPI:1,0,0 SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
   >
   > growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr1=SUU_14.03.00_A00.iso
   > ```
   >
   > Other benefits to firmware upgrade are probable.  For instance, the
   >   PX-750A-UF 1.01 firmware device wrote the dual layer DVD at about 2.4x
   >   but the 1.03 firmware wrote the media at a 6x rate.

Concerning the layer break, it was interesting to observe `cdrecord` pausing a long time at the 4023 MB point (half way) and right before the 4025 MB point where `cdrecord` failed when working with the drive when it had the older firmware.  It had the appearance that the delay may have been due to a layer switch operation.

Comment: Never use dev=ATAPI as Linux has several drivers for the same hardware and you force cdrecord to use a worse driver than it would autoselect. If you only have one CD drive, I recommend to ommit dev= completely as cdrecord since 2004 tries to find the drive.

Comment: @schily, I tried to use growisofs on Ubuntu Linux 14,04 LTS earlier this evening and it said genisomage cannot backup directory tree depths greater than 6. How might I workaround that problem? Thank you.

Comment: `genisoimage` is an unmaintained copy from the `mkisofs` state from May 2004 with some `Debian specific bugs` added. If you use `genisoimage` instead of the original software, you miss more than half of the development efforts. Check the man page at http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html and use the option `-R` to enable `Rock Ridge` **or** use `-iso-level 4` if you really like to stay with `DOS`-semantics. Note that unlike genisoimage the original software does not have a visible directory `rr_moved` with deep `directory relocation` in `Rock Ridge` mode.

Answer (score -2):

If you did not tell cdrecord where to put the layer break, the drive will fill up the media up to 100%. This causes a long delay.

If cdrecord fails, you may be a victim of various modified versions that ripped off DVD support and replaced the original code with something half baken. These defective versions do not report version 3 and they do not know about the right timeouts for DVD writing. This may be a reason for cdrecord timing out too early.

The recent version of cdrecord is 3.01a31 and there will soon be 3.01-final.

Did you use a recent version?

Comment: Sorry, I just see that I was replying to a partial thread that missed the cdrecord status report. Your problem is most likely the fact that use told cdrecord to use a bad driver that does not support DMA. So don't use a dev= parameter at all (if you only have a single drive in the system) or use a vanilla dev=b,t,l version but never use ATAPI without exactly knowing what to do.