# Backup a 50Megbyte ubuntu linux subdirectory tree to a LG Ultra Slim Portable DVD Writer

Tags: ubuntu, backup, dvd

I would like to backup my 50 megabyte home directory `/home/frankc` on my Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS desktop Lenovo computer using a LG Ultra Slim Portable DVD Writer. The directions for the LG Ultra Slim Portable DVD Writer are written for Microsoft Windows and Apple MacIntosh. The salesman told me this evening  that the  LG Ultra Slim Portable DVD Writer can store and write one megabyte of files.

I am using the Ubuntu Linux in GRUB recovery mode with read write privileges and `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` not set in environment so I get the `Gtk - Warning ** cannot open display`.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131519/command-line-to-burn-dvdr-dl-media-on-linux?rq=1) answers a related question but it does not answer mine.

Please tell me how to do this quickly and accurately. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to use growisofs on Ubuntu Linux 14,04 LTS earlier this evening and it said genisomage cannot backup directory tree depths greater than 6. How might I workaround that problem? Thank you.

Comment: backup is open source, and you can write the back folder to a dvd using your portable dvd writer. How do I use wget in grub recovery mode to download backup for linux?

Comment: Are you attempting to copy your home directory onto a DVD? It sounds like you are trying to somehow copy your data onto the DVD writer's internal memory (that's what I understand by "the [...] DVD Writer can store and write one megabyte of files". If so, and if the salesman told you it can hold only 1M, how would you write 50M of data to it? Why are you in grub recovery mode? Is your machine broken? What command gives the gtk error? How do the answers you linked to not answer your question? How did they fail? What did you try? Please [edit] and clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to backup your home directory, then you need not
necessarily to be in recovery mode. That would only be needed
if you want a complete snapshot of your system disk. 
Just don't change files in the home directory while the backup
is running.

Try this:

```
xorriso -for_backup -outdev /dev/sr0 -blank as_needed -map "$HOME" /
```

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

(I edited this answer to put quotation marks around $HOME. Just in case ...)

Comment: Schmiit, What is the repository for xorriso if the package xorriso is not available? Thank you.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for butchering the spelling of your  name . I have not had any sleep for 24 hours.  What is the repository for xorriso if the package xorriso is not available? I am going to get 3 hours of sleep now.

Comment: (Just call me Thomas. That's international.)
Look for "libisoburn". Alternatively get the standalone
source tarball of GNU xorriso:
(https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/xorriso-1.4.2.tar.gz) .
See (https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/README_xorriso)
for "Compilation, First Glimpse, Installation".

Comment: I wonder, though, why you could not find (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xorriso)